# Modifiy deeply nested dependencies

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, dependencies

What is the proper way of accessing/modifying deeply nested objects?

Look at the example below.

```
public class DrawBoard
{
    MouseTracker mouseTracker_;
    DrawTool* drawTool_;

    void init()
    {
        mouseTracker_ = new MouseTracker(area);
        mouseTracker_.setTool(new PenTool());
    }

    void OnMouseEvent(MouseEvent e)
    {
        mouseTracker_->handleMouseEvent(e);
    }

    //UI Button setting the tool
    void OnPenButtonClick()
    {
        mouseTracker_.SetTool(new PenTool());
    }

    void OnLineButtonClick()
    {
        mouseTracker_.SetTool(new LineTool());
    }

    void OnCircleButtonClick()
    {
        mouseTracker_.SetTool(new CircleTool());
    }

    //UI slide bar changing the color
    void OnColorSlideBarChange(int color)
    {
        //What should I do here?
        //Chained getters : mouseTracker.getDrawTool().setColor(color);
        //Delegate Method: mouseTracker.setColor(color);
        //Shared Object: Store the current tool in "drawTool_" -    drawTool_ = new PenTool(); 
        //                                                          mouseTracker_.SetTool(drawTool_);
        //and just call drawTool_.setColor(color) on color change
    }
}

public class MouseTracker;
{
    DrawTool* tool_;

    void handleMouseEvent(MouseEvent e)
    {
        Shape s = tool->process(e)
        s.Draw();
    }

    void SetTool(DrawTool tool)
    {
        tool_ = tool;
    }
}

public class DrawTool
{
    int color_;

    Shape* process(MouseEvent e)
    {
        /** process e **/
        Shape s = new Pen\Line\Circle(color_);
        return s;
    }

    void SetColor(int color)
    {
        color_ = color;
    }

} PenTool, LineTool, CircleTool;

public class Shape
{
    void Draw() {  Implementation };

} Pen, Line, Circle;
```

`DrawBoard` is a UI class.

`MouseTracker` is a class used to process events and act accordingly.

`DrawTool` is the class used to create `Shapes`. `PenTool`, `LineTool`, `CircleTool` are subclasses of it.

`Shape` is the class used to draw. `Pen`, `Line`, `Circle` are subclasses of it.

Now from DrawBoard, I'm trying to change the color of the drawTool based from an UI event(OnColorSlideBarChange in this case). I can only see 3 ways of doing it.

**Chained getters**

`mouseTracker.getDrawTool().setColor(color);` 
But the example above is a simplified case. If there is more dependencies in between.It could quickly grow into

`mouseTracker.getA().getB().getC().getDrawTool().setColor(color);` And I'll have to write a getter method for each class.

**Delegate Method**

`mouseTracker.setColor(color)`;

Similar to above, except I hide the details in one delegate method.

**Shared Object**

Store the current tool in "drawTool_" within `DrawBoard` class, and update it on every tool change

```
drawTool_ = new PenTool(); 
mouseTracker_.SetTool(drawTool_);
```

Changing the color would simply be

```
drawTool_.setColor(color)
```

But it seems like I'm breaking encapsulation doing it this way.

Is there better ways of handling this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last example using a shared object isn't really breaking encapsulation and is close to the way I would recommend doing it by combining the concepts of dependency inversion and separation of concerns.

The only thing I would question is why the mouse tracker cares what tool is currently being used.  Based on its name, it should only be concerned with tracking the mouse and determining positional data; possibly wrapping some convenience methods to determine state like perhaps an `IsDragging` property.  The controller class (in this case the drawing board) should then take that data (and/or respond to mouse state change events published by your tracker) and use it, in conjunction with the results produced by the tool, to update your drawing space.

With all of that said, the answer to your original question is to look at that sort of deep access as a coding smell and make sure you can't alter the design using SOLID principles and common patterns.  If your design does require deep access, determine on a case by case basis whether consumers will need deep access to complete objects or a single property.  If the former, expose the child object.  If the latter, create a wrapper property that gets what you want. Make that decision at each level, and then access the deepest available properties at each level.  Basically you just have to find a balance between not wanting to expose everything, and not wanting to always have a billion properties on each object to access deeper objects.

Comment: I was thinking of "flattening" the structure too. The MouseTracker will fire a event, and then the tool will respond to this event and draw. But I thought it might expose some implementation detail in the controller class. I guess I'm "overthinking" about this encapsulation thing. For now I would go with the shared object method :)